# Модификация public static class

Tags: c#, asp.net

В отдельном классе есть `List<T>`. Каким образом из другого класса возможно модифицировать `List<T>`? Как получить к нему доступ?

Comment: Ну задайте этому листу сеттер или, если есть необходимость модифицировать только отдельные элементы, индексатор

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class - имя класса

```
class Class{
    public static List<T> list .....
}

///Далее где вам нужно в коде 
Class.list ....
```